# optimize jquery hover for menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these menu items:

```
<li class="mainMenuItem menuTour">
    <a href="#">Tour</a>
    <div class="sub_nav closed" data-grid-id="sub_menu_stay">
        bla bla bla
    </div>
</li>
<li class="mainMenuItem">
    <a href="#">Offer</a>
    <div class="sub_nav closed" data-grid-id="sub_menu_stay">
        bla bla bla
    </div>
</li>
<!-- more repeated here... -->
```

I have this jQuery code:

```
$('.menuTour').mouseenter( function(){
    $('.menuTour > div').removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
}).mouseleave( function(){
    $('.menuTour > div').removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
});
```

How can I optimize this code to work for all `mainMenuItem` elements? On `mainMenuItem` hover I want the same thing for every menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in CSS alone:

```css
.mainMenuItem:hover div {
    display: block;
}
.mainMenuItem div {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="mainMenuItem menuTour">
    <a href="#">Tour</a>
    <div class="sub_nav" data-grid-id="sub_menu_stay">
        bla bla bla
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="mainMenuItem">
    <a href="#">Offer</a>
    <div class="sub_nav" data-grid-id="sub_menu_stay">
        bla bla bla
    </div>
  </li>
<ul>
```